Can't Figure Out How to Add Histogram with Density Curve
I have been working on a general plotting function for a while, and it does pretty much everything I want it to show me, however I can't get it to display a histogram along with the density curve.
My current code:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(PupillometryR)
library(tidyr)
library(moments)

raincloud_summary <- function(dataframe, variable, grouping_variable = NULL) {
  text_vjust = 1
  add_legend <- !is.null(grouping_variable) && grouping_variable %in% names(dataframe)
  
  if (!add_legend) {
    dataframe$grouping <- "Overall"
    grouping_variable <- "grouping"
  }
  
  lower_limit <- quantile(dataframe[[variable]], probs = 0.0, na.rm = T)
  upper_limit <- quantile(dataframe[[variable]], probs = 1.0, na.rm = T)
  
  p <- ggplot(dataframe, aes_string(y = variable, fill = grouping_variable, x = grouping_variable)) +
    geom_flat_violin(kernel = "gaussian", bw = "nrd0", position = position_nudge(x = 0.15, y = 0), adjust = 1, trim = F) +
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.1) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.15, outlier.shape = 1, stat = "boxplot", show.legend = F) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 3, color = "white", show.legend = F) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(lower_limit, upper_limit)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(text = element_text(size=11),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          axis.text.x = if(add_legend) element_text(hjust = -1) else element_blank(),
          legend.position = if (add_legend) "right" else "none") +
    labs(fill = if (add_legend) grouping_variable else NULL, x = NULL) +
    ggtitle(variable) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", guide = if (add_legend) "legend" else "none",
                      limits = rev(levels(factor(dataframe[[grouping_variable]]))))
  
  p <- p + coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
  
  group_stats <- dataframe %>%
    group_by(!!sym(grouping_variable)) %>%
    summarise(
      `Min.` = min(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      `Q1` = quantile(!!sym(variable), probs = 0.25, na.rm = T),
      `Median (Q2)` = median(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      Mean = mean(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      `Q3` = quantile(!!sym(variable), probs = 0.75, na.rm = T),
      `Max.` = max(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      IQR = IQR(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      SD = sd(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      Variance = var(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      Skewness = skewness(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      Kurtosis = kurtosis(!!sym(variable), na.rm = T),
      Count = n(),
      .groups = "drop"
    ) %>%
    pivot_longer(-grouping_variable, names_to = "stat", values_to = "value") %>%
    mutate(value = round(value, 2))
  print(group_stats)
  group_levels <- levels(factor(dataframe[[grouping_variable]]))
  x_positions <- setNames(seq_along(group_levels)-0.05, group_levels)
  for (group in group_levels) {
    left_labels <- group_stats %>%
      filter(!!sym(grouping_variable) == group, stat %in% c("Min.", "Q1", "Median (Q2)", "Mean", "Q3", "Max.")) %>%
      mutate(label = paste(stat, ": ", value, sep="")) %>%
      pull(label) %>%
      paste(collapse = "\n")
    
    right_labels <- group_stats %>%
      filter(!!sym(grouping_variable) == group, stat %in% c("IQR", "SD", "Variance", "Skewness", "Kurtosis", "Count")) %>%
      mutate(label = paste(stat, ": ", value, sep="")) %>%
      pull(label) %>%
      paste(collapse = "\n")
    
    gap <- (upper_limit - lower_limit) / 5
    p <- p + annotate("text", x = x_positions[group] + 1, y = lower_limit, label = left_labels,
                      hjust = 0, vjust = text_vjust, size = 3, parse = F)
    p <- p + annotate("text", x = x_positions[group] + 1, y = lower_limit + gap, label = right_labels,
                      hjust = 0, vjust = text_vjust, size = 3, parse = F)
  }
  
  dataframe$grouping <- NULL
  print(p)
  return(group_stats)
}

Example usage:
data(iris)
raincloud_summary(iris, "Sepal.Width", "Species")

Current output:

Desired output with histogram should be something like this:


I understand you may have your reasons for this, but do you really think overlaying histograms and density plots will add clarity to the plot? To me, it looks like it would only get more clumsy. Moreover, histograms will rarely reliably show the distribution as well as density plots (which is quite clear from youor own example), I would usually not use them at all.

If you need a "one plot fits all" approach, you may consider using an ECDF (or Empirical Cumulative Density Function) plot. It may be a bit less mainstream, but is more reliable and comprehensive than this multi-methods plot approach

I agree with GuedesBF - There doesn't seem to be a reason to complicate this so much. To me, statistical annotations inside the plot like that create a lot of clutter. Depending on plot size and output image size, the text will also become very hard to format. I would recommend this other very simple approach to get to a raincloud plot and include a side by side table if the stats are important to the story.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrain)

data(iris)
iris %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
    geom_rain()


